# Angular 4 accessing json file under assets in IIS

Tags: angular, iis, angular2-routing

I am working on a Angular 4 app built from CLI, while the back end API is still under development, I have set up some json files under assets folder for http.get.  Everything works well on my local, but when I deploy to IIS, in the Network tab of the dev tool, I see the 404 when trying to access the json file.  The way I am setting up the URL in my code is hard coded 'assets/api/manager/model.json'. I built the project by running npm build --prod and copied over the content in dist folder.  I do see the assets/api/manager/model.json file under dist after the build.  I see that there are various ways of tweaking on the routes when hosting on IIS and I have tried them all (I think) but can't seem to get it to work.

Below is the http.get code

```
  private assignTasksViewModelUrl = 'assets/api/manager/model.json';
   getTaskAssignmentViewModel(): Observable<AssignTasksViewModel> {

    return this.http.get(this.assignTasksViewModelUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <AssignTasksViewModel>(this.extractDate(response)))
            .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 7):

Add  works for me. Just a reminder the tag should be inside 
 :

```
<system.webServer>
   ...
   <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
   </staticContent>
   ...
</system.webServer>
```

The other way is go to IIS Manager to add MIME Types to it.

Go to IIS Manager --> open your website --> click "Feature View" tab on the right side --> MIME Types(Double click) --> Actions: Add (right side) --> 
File name extension:  .json,  MIME Type: application/json.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else having the same problem.  My problem was our IIS was not configured to handle .json file.  By adding the following to the web.config solves the problem.

```html
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".json" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
```